# android studio app folder is missing. How to show it again?

Tags: android, android-studio

after I did the last update, the order app is no longer displayed

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DChOw.jpg)

how can I show this again?

Answer (score 0):

Tap on Project -> Select Project (You have selected Android rightnow)

[image]

Comment: is there another method to get the old view back? under project this is not pleasant and very annoying because everything is messy

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this cannot be displayed again due to the setting of Android Studio.
There are 3 solutions that were an option for me:

1. Simply open the files app under "Project".
2. Create a new project and add all of your app's files to it.
3. Uninstall Android Studio and reinstall it!

And in general, the 1st solution is sufficient, because this is only a view of the app files. It doesn't change the app :)